# Virtuoso java API to load OntModel

Tags: java, jena, ontology, virtuoso

Using Jena API I created an `OntModel` and printed it as a file. Now I would like to load it into Virtuoso.

I successfully done it using Virtuoso Conductor web manager but I would like to do the same directly using java API, for instance loading from the generated file or directly from the created `OntModel`. Is this possible? I have not found anything about it.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Virtuoso Jena Provider documentation](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtJenaProvider)?  Or the [Jena documentation](https://jena.apache.org/) in general? Or the generalized [RDF Loading documentation for Virtuoso](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtRDFInsert)? Here's another [Java-specific example](https://www.openlinksw.com/vos/main/Main/VirtTipsAndTricksLoadDataInTransactionMode#Using%20the%20Virtuoso%20JDBC%20Driver).  And also [this page of the manual, with Jena LOAD examples](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfnativestorageprovidersjena/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it via the [Dataset](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/query/Dataset.html) interface. For that you need to add the Jena Provider and Virtuoso JDBC Driver [libraries](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VOSDownload#Jena%20Provider) to your project first. Then you can connect to your Virtuoso instance and add the model:

```
VirtDataset ds = new VirtDataset("localhost:1111", "dba", "dba");
ds.addNamedModel("http://example.com", model);
```

You could also use the Graph Store Protocol with [DatasetAccessor](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/query/DatasetAccessor.html) / [DatasetAccessorFactory](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/query/DatasetAccessorFactory.html), the [RDFConnection](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/rdfconnection/) interface or the SPARQL endpoint directly by using [UpdateRequest](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/update/UpdateRequest.html) / [UpdateFactory](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/update/UpdateFactory.html).